# Error in super methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt5

I try using PyQt5 to connect two ellipses with a line. To do this, slightly changed the class taken with github. Instead of PySide, i use PyQt5.
The code is taken from here: https://github.com/PySide/Examples/blob/master/examples/graphicsview/diagramscene/diagramscene.py

```
class Arrow(QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, start_item, end_item, parent=None, scene=None):
        super(Arrow, self).__init__(parent, scene)

        self.arrowHead = QPolygonF()

        self.my_start_item = start_item
        self.my_end_item = end_item
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.my_color = QtCore.Qt.black
        self.setPen(QPen(self.my_color, 2, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine,
                    QtCore.Qt.RoundCap, QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin))

    def set_color(self, color):
        self.my_color = color

    def start_item(self):
        return self.my_start_item

    def end_item(self):
        return self.my_end_item

    def boundingRect(self):
        extra = (self.pen().width() + 20) / 2.0
        p1 = self.line().p1()
        p2 = self.line().p2()
        return QtCore.QRectF(p1, QtCore.QSizeF(p2.x() - p1.x(), p2.y() - p1.y())).normalized().adjusted(-extra, -extra, extra, extra)

    def shape(self):
        path = super(Arrow, self).shape()
        path.addPolygon(self.arrowHead)
        return path

    def update_position(self):
        line = QtCore.QLineF(self.mapFromItem(self.my_start_item, 0, 0), self.mapFromItem(self.my_end_item, 0, 0))
        self.setLine(line)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        if self.my_start_item.collidesWithItem(self.my_end_item):
            return

        my_start_item = self.my_start_item
        my_end_item = self.my_end_item
        my_color = self.my_color
        my_pen = self.pen()
        my_pen.setColor(self.my_color)
        arrow_size = 20.0
        painter.setPen(my_pen)
        painter.setBrush(self.my_color)

        center_line = QtCore.QLineF(my_start_item.pos(), my_end_item.pos())
        end_polygon = my_end_item.polygon()
        p1 = end_polygon.at(0) + my_end_item.pos()

        intersect_point = QtCore.QPointF()
        for i in end_polygon:
            p2 = i + my_end_item.pos()
            poly_line = QtCore.QLineF(p1, p2)
            intersect_type, intersect_point = poly_line.intersect(center_line)
            if intersect_type == QtCore.QLineF.BoundedIntersection:
                break
            p1 = p2

        self.setLine(QtCore.QLineF(intersect_point, my_start_item.pos()))
        line = self.line()

        angle = math.acos(line.dx() / line.length())
        if line.dy() >= 0:
            angle = (math.pi * 2.0) - angle

        arrow_p1 = line.p1() + QtCore.QPointF(math.sin(angle + math.pi / 3.0) * arrow_size,
                                              math.cos(angle + math.pi / 3) * arrow_size)
        arrow_p2 = line.p1() + QtCore.QPointF(math.sin(angle + math.pi - math.pi / 3.0) * arrow_size,
                                              math.cos(angle + math.pi - math.pi / 3.0) * arrow_size)

        self.arrowHead.clear()
        for point in [line.p1(), arrow_p1, arrow_p2]:
            self.arrowHead.append(point)

        painter.drawLine(line)
        painter.drawPolygon(self.arrowHead)
        if self.isSelected():
            painter.setPen(QPen(my_color, 1, QtCore.Qt.DashLine))
            my_line = QtCore.QLineF(line)
            my_line.translate(0, 4.0)
            painter.drawLine(my_line)
            my_line.translate(0, -8.0)
            painter.drawLine(my_line)
```

Creating a arrow

```
  arrow = Arrow(start, end, scene=scene)
  scene.addItem(arrow)
  arrow.update_position()
```

Error that occurs when the code is run

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyQt5 is a wrapper of Qt5 created by the company riverbankcomputing, and PySide is a wrapper of Qt4 created by the same creators of Qt at the time. Besides Qt4 and Qt5 have many differences, so these libraries are not compatible at all, for example in your case PySide items you can pass the scene as a parameter, but in the case of PyQt4 or PyQt5 that parameter is unnecessary:

**PySide:**

> class PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem([parent=None[, scene=None]])
>
> class PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem(line[, parent=None[, scene=None]])
>
> class PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem(x1, y1, x2, y2[,parent=None[, scene=None]])

**PyQt5:**

> QGraphicsLineItem(parent: QGraphicsItem = None)
>
> QGraphicsLineItem(QLineF, parent: QGraphicsItem = None)
>
> QGraphicsLineItem(float, float, float, float, parent: QGraphicsItem = None)

Besides that difference are the classes `Signal()` and `pyqtSignal`, and obviously the step from Qt4 to Qt5 supposed the separation of some classes that belonged to QtGui to QtWidgets.

The solution in your case is to eliminate the scene parameter, for it changes:

```
class Arrow(QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, start_item, end_item, parent=None, scene=None):
        super(Arrow, self).__init__(parent, scene)
```

to:

```
class Arrow(QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, start_item, end_item, parent=None):
        super(Arrow, self).__init__(parent)
```

I have translated that project to PyQt5, you can check it in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/diagramscene-47928724).

Comment: The code is taken from your link, the program crashes with the error code "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)"


`start = scene.addEllipse(50, 50, 100, 100)
end = scene.addEllipse(150, 150, 100, 100)
arrow = Arrow(start, end)
scene.addItem(arrow)
arrow.updatePosition()`

Comment: @SergeyAndSmart Those lines is not part of the code that I have proposed, have you modified my code?

Comment: Yes. The beginning of the class is now
`class Arrow(QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, start_item, end_item, parent=None):
        super(Arrow, self).__init__(parent)`

Comment: Share your code to check what is the problem (It would be great to be through github or similar), and do not say that it is my code, since making any modification is already your code. :P

Comment: I have tested your code and it does not generate any errors. At what moment does the error generate you?

Comment: It works for me: https://imgur.com/a/b18OH , I recommend you to execute it from the CMD, generally you give more information. What version of Python3 do you have and what version of PyQt5?

Comment: CMD: https://imgur.com/a/WDNNf And you do not get the lines drawn? I want to connect the ellipses with a line. Python version 3.6, PyQt version 5.9.2.

Comment: the error indicates that end_polygon (which inherits from QGraphicsEllipseItem) does not have the polygon() method. Where have you implemented the polygon() method?

Comment: Does it only generate that error when starting the application, or do you have to execute a command or procedure? Is the code you have shared with me the same one you are testing?

Comment: And where to implement it? I have the code exactly as you do on the github. You also have this method. An error occurred while executing the entire program through the Run in PyCharm.Yes, the code I filled in on the githab and my code are completely identical.

Comment: Where have you implemented the polygon() method?

Comment: or why do you use the polygon() method?

Comment: String 65 https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/blob/master/diagramscene-47928724/diagramscene.py I completely copied the class from the githab, just changed the variable names so that PyCharm did not display errors.

Comment: Maybe we need another class with a githab to connect two ellipses with a line?

Comment: QGraphicsPolygonItem has the polygon method, instead you are using QGraphicsEllipseItem through the addEllipse () method, what do you want to do, do you want to join the circles with a line ?, if so, what points do you want to join ?, in the if a polygon is joined by the vertices, and in the circles by which points do you want to join?

Comment: I want to get this https://imgur.com/a/XOQfk Do I need to add ellipses differently?

Comment: Ok, I understand, I'll do that later and I'll give you the solution, but on the other hand I think my answer has answered your question and it deserves to be marked as correct, so please do it.

Comment: @SergeyAndSmart see this code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/c48edc666318ae4dc59debd1681ee169